# Two users attempt to modify a page

Tags: user-access

I trust you are doing well

I am made a test to modify a page as an administration and an editor using incognito window for the user role editor.

I have noticed even if the administrator or editor complete the editing of a page and logout.

The notice takeover take some time to disappeared, it is instantly.

Can anyone please advised me, the approximate time interval it takes for the notice to disappear?

Thank you team

[image]